# Monodroid - GC.Collect fails without any reason

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android

I have an application with 4 tabs (TabActivity). By some reasons I call GC.Collect every time user switches tab (overriding OnPause Activity's method). Sometimes (approximately 1 time from 50-100 calls, but sometimes this happens when application just started) my application hangs in this moment.

Here is part of my code:

```
protected override void OnPause(){
  base.OnPause();

  try{
    Android.Util.Log.Info("----","GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);");
    GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
    Android.Util.Log.Info("----","GC.Collect Finished");
  }catch(Exception exc){
    Android.Util.Log.Info("exc.Message",exc.Message);
    Android.Util.Log.Info("exc.StackTrace",exc.StackTrace);
    throw exc;
  }
}
```

And here is corresponding Android log output

```
//Previous GC.Collect call, it's all ok
I/----    ( 7796): GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
D/dalvikvm( 7796): GetMethodID: method not found: Landroid/widget/EditText;.monodroidAddReference:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
D/dalvikvm( 7796): GC_EXPLICIT freed 962 objects / 42472 bytes in 112ms
I/----    ( 7796): GC.Collect Finished
//On another call fails
I/----    ( 7796): GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
I/mono    ( 7796): Stacktrace:
I/mono    ( 7796): 
I/mono    ( 7796):   at System.GC.Collect (int) <0x0001f>
I/mono    ( 7796):   at System.GC.Collect (int,System.GCCollectionMode) <0x00017>
I/mono    ( 7796):   at PixelsAndroid.CustomActivity.OnPause () <0x00067>
I/mono    ( 7796):   at Android.App.Activity.n_OnPause (intptr,intptr) <0x00037>
I/mono    ( 7796):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.908cefd4-40eb-4dd1-97cd-f731b2ada74a (intptr,intptr) <0x0002b>
I/mono    ( 7796):   at (wrapper native-to-managed) object.908cefd4-40eb-4dd1-97cd-f731b2ada74a (intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>
```

No any exception to been thrown, no any visible reason to fail. Application just hangs, after few seconds I get Android OS alert: "Oppps, your application got stuck. Force close or wait?"

Anybody faced with it?

Comment: Why are you calling GC.Collect() in the first place? I have NEVER had a valid reason to force a GC on MonoDroid or Windows for that matter. When I see GC.Collect(), it is a code smell that needs rethinking.

Comment: I use it like a particular solution of [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7603135/monodroid-passing-data-to-listview-according-to-gref-limit)

Comment: Reduce the number of instances you load. Let be frank: if your code loads so many list items that you are hitting the GREF limit (ie. you are not paging the data), then you need to redesign your solution. Remember, this IS a mobile device and not your laptop/desktop/whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in some old versions of monodroid: if you call GC.Collect and an http request in a parallel threads, this caused crash. Update to a latest version of monodroid.

Answer (score 0):

Having to do a GC.Collect() under any circumstance is a bad code smell. Figure out the underlying reason and perform corrective rearchitecture.