# Monodroid - free memory when activity finished

Tags: xamarin.android

Here can be found a sample code
https://github.com/PVoLan/TestActivityDispose

We have two activities. One has a button leading to second activity. Second activity has 30 TextViews (simulating a complex UI) and a back button.

Switching between activities forward and back causes GREF quantity growing quickly. It requires about 60 times to click forward and back to overflow 2k limit and crash application.

Android log can be found in repository. As you can see from log, GREF overflow occurs most because of TextViews (1543 GREFs). Another GREFS are:

- Button (55 GREFs) - backButton, obviously
- OnClickListenerImplementor (55 GREFs) - backButton.Click listenters
- Activity2 (54 GREFs)
- Intent (54 GREFs) - activity starters

So, as we can see, activity resources are not freed when activity finishes (although OnDestroy is called)
How can I free all this GREFs properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there are two GCs in the process (Dalvik & Mono), and neither knows how much memory the other is using. For example, all Mono sees for `TextView` instances is a really small object (largely an `IntPtr` and other supporting fields from `Java.Lang.Object`):

```csharp
namespace Java.Lang {
    public class Object {
        IntPtr handle;
        // ...
    }
}
namespace Android.Widget {
    public class TextView : Java.Lang.Object {
        // ...
    }
}
```

That is, for most of the bound types, there are no data members of consequence, and the C# wrappers are quite tiny. Mono doesn't know -- and can't know -- that there's a Java object associated with `Object.handle`, and (more importantly) how much memory that object is referencing.

Consequently, you occasionally need to help it:

```csharp
// https://github.com/PVoLan/TestActivityDispose/blob/master/Test/Activity2.cs
public class Activity2 {
    // ...
    protected override void OnDestroy ()
    {
        Android.Util.Log.Info("----------", "Destroy");
        base.OnDestroy ();
        GC.Collect ();
    }
}
```

The added `GC.Collect()` call will give Mono's GC a chance to execute and collect the garbage objects. After adding that line, repeatedly tapping "Hello World, Click Me!" and "Back" levels out at 93-126 grefs (depending on which activity you're on).

Comment: This works on test sample, but on my real project this causes unexpected exception, [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599737/monodroid-gc-collect-fails-without-any-reason). I've heard about some problems with GC in monodroid. When this question was posted, I've used 1.0.2 version of monodroid. Now I use the latest beta (updated just 4-5 days ago), but problem is still actual.

Comment: @PVoLan: try rebooting your device and see if that helps.

Comment: Tried to reboot emulator and use clear HTC. No effect. I'm also trying to represent exception on test sample, but still can't catch it. I'll notify you, if I'll succeeded

Comment: I've got it. My application is online-client, so every few seconds it requests tcp connection to the server for some updates. A bug is somewhere around. Here is a [sample code](https://github.com/PVoLan/TestTCP). This code creates a tcp send/response to google.com every 3 seconds. GC can be called manually by clicking a button. Launch it and click "GC.Collect" few times. Usually it requires for me 1-10 clicks to get an exception I described above.